# Trim Series/DataFrame on the basis of quantile values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, quantile

Is there any mrthod in pandas to trim the `Series/DataFrame` based on the quantile values?

For Example if I have a `ser=pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])`

how can I get the series where the data is between `0.27>Data>0.82` of the original `ser`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`Series.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html):

```
a = ser.quantile([0.27, 0.82])
print (a)
0.27    2.89
0.82    6.74
dtype: float64

s,e = a
out = ser[ser.between(s, e, inclusive=False)]
print (out)
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
dtype: int64
```

Or:

```
out = ser[ser.between(ser.quantile(0.27), 
                      ser.quantile(0.82), inclusive=False)]
```